# Filtering laravel resultset (collections) fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In **Filtering Collections** laravel gives this example:

```php
$users = $users->filter(function ($user) {
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return $user;
    }
});
```

Using the example I constructed a filter:

```php
$links = DB::table('links')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->remember(60)->take(1000)->get();

$imageLinks = $links->filter(function ($link) {
    if (! empty($link->image_src)) {
        return $link->toArray();
    }
});
```

However, this throws the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function filter() on a non-object

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Since Laravel 5.3, the query builder returns its results as a collection. No need to manually wrap it.

---

Currently, only Eloquent returns a collection. For now, regular database results have to be wrapped in a collection yourself:

```
$links = DB::table('links')->latest()->take(1000)->get();

$imageLinks = collect($links)->filter($callback);
```

---

BTW, it doesn't matter what you return. If it's truthy, the original item is in the returned filtered collection.

[The docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) actually return `true`:

```php
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item > 2;
});

$filtered->all();

// [3, 4]
```

Comment: This gives `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function collect()`. I realize the docs you mention are for Laravel 5.1. Could `collect()` only exist for 5.1? I am using 4.2.

Comment: Yes. `collect()` is not present in 4.2. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

You can use `new Collection()` though.

Comment: @Curos Can't locate `new Collection()` under 4.2 docs, even the helper functions mentioned.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba - Documentation for collections were [only added in laravel 5.1](https://github.com/laravel/docs/commit/2d3453b2f9c00ee0f99bd3297a9eefa95156cfc9).

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba but, collections did exist in 4.2 though. Read the API docs : http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html

Comment: @Curos - Thanks. Will try it out.